# Apple script to change a colour of an SVG prompting a message in finder to include the new HEX code, copy it in the clipboard with the new color

Tags: svg, applescript

I'm trying to do an apple script that can do the following:

I have an icon SVG called "bubble.svg" in a folder in a folder called "test" in the desktop.
Is it possible to create an apple script to change the hex colour of the icon so that when I will run the script it will prompt me a window to include the new HEX colour of the icon, and copy the svg with the new colour to the clipboard so that I can past it in application with the new colour?

I used the following code and get this error

```
 on run
    set theHex to text returned of (display dialog "Enter the new HEX color for the icon:" default answer "#FFFFFF")
    set theFile to (choose file with prompt "Select the SVG file to modify:")
    set theFileContents to read file theFile
    set theFileContents to (do shell script "sed 's/#000000/" & theHex & "/g' < " & theFile)
    set theFile to open for access theFile with write permission
    write theFileContents to theFile starting at eof
    close access theFile
    set the clipboard to theHex
end run
```

In can include the new colour and the select the file, but then I get the following error

```
ERROR error "sh: Macintosh: No such file or directory" number 1
```

Can you help me?
Thank you!
[image]

I used the following

```
on run
    set theHex to text returned of (display dialog "Enter the new HEX color for the icon:" default answer "#FFFFFF")
    set theFile to (choose file with prompt "Select the SVG file to modify:")
    set theFileContents to read file theFile
    set theFileContents to (do shell script "sed 's/#000000/" & theHex & "/g' < " & theFile)
    set theFile to open for access theFile with write permission
    write theFileContents to theFile starting at eof
    close access theFile
    set the clipboard to theHex
end run
```

Comment: Do you really mean to append (i.e. add) the original SVG to the end of the modified file?

Comment: Can you please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text? [See here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See [/editing-help#code](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Comment: 'Can somebody help me?' is not a "real question" by our community's standards! Can you please [read this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541) to learn why and how to ask a better question? You can also see [ask] for guidance.

Comment: I think you have to use the `posix path of (theFile)` if you want the bash shell to understand the filename.